# Ubuntu 14.04 just update and very slow

Tags: unity, 14.04, graphics, performance, catalyst

So I just updated from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04, and I noticed that my system (specifically animations and videos) are very slow.
I disabled the animations, which helped. But its still working very slow, especially with flash, silverlight and video. I checked my drivers all up to date. Here are my specs:

- Memory: 3.6 GiB
- Processor: AMD Phenom(tm) 9500 Quad-Core Processor × 4
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
- Ubuntu 64bit

Also something weird that happens sometimes is that my Dash App doesn't work properly. It disappears too quickly (I suspect this has to do more with disabling my animations with Unity Tweak).

Comment: Yes i do have a 4 quad processor

Comment: It would be better if you provide the graphic card model

Comment: So you have 16 cores?

Comment: I am going to revert to 12.04, it works much better than 14.04 which I find slow and lots of the apps don't yet function.

Comment: No, dont do that. Just reinstall your graphics drivers

Answer (score 1):

So I seem to have solves this.
It was really obvious and sad that I missed it.
When I did the update, for some reason I lost the driver I was using to run my graphics card. 
I reinstalled it, and configured it as I had it before the update, now everything works as it should work.

Comment: Can you also specify which driver is correct for you?

Comment: well I just installed the AMD Catalyst Control centre,through: 
sudo apt-get install fglrx
sudo amdconfig --initial
sudo apt-get install gksu

Mind you, only do this, if your graphics card is AMD.